# TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined (por si acaso es con el comando snipe, no funciona el messagedelete ni el messageupdate)

Tags: nodejs

Este es del messagedelete

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = async (client, messageDelete) => {

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

  .setTitle("Mensaje borrado")
  .setDescription(`Mensaje: **${messageDelete}**\nAutor: **${messageDelete.author.tag}**\nCanal: **${messageDelete.channel}**\nID: **${messageDelete.id}**`)
  .setColor("RED")
  .setTimestamp()

  client.channels.cache.get('933115012015349850').send({ embeds : [embed] })
  
}
```

Y este es del messageupdate

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports = async (client, oldMessage, newMessage) => {

  const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

  .setTitle("Mensaje editado")
  .setDescription(`Antiguo mensaje: **${oldMessage}**\nNuevo mensaje: **${newMessage}**\nAutor: **${newMessage.author.tag}**\nCanal: **${oldMessage.channel.name}**\nID: **${newMessage.id}**`)
  .setColor("GREEN")
  .setTimestamp()

  client.channels.cache.get('933115012015349850').send({ embeds : [embed] })
  
}
```

Este es el error

````
/home/runner/asdaad/eventos/messageDelete.js:12
  client.channels.cache.get('933115012015349850').send({ embeds : [embed] })
                                                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at module.exports (/home/runner/asdaad/eventos/messageDelete.js:12:50)
    at Client.emit (node:events:406:35)
    at MessageDeleteAction.handle (/home/runner/asdaad/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageDelete.js:24:16)
    ```
````

Comment: Checa que el ID sea el correcto, agrega una validación para verificar que lo que regresa no este vacio `if (!channel) return console.log('No existe canal');`

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!